# Unable to understand why I cannot install laravel-datatables

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-datatables

I'm mantaining an old project, started with laravel 5.4, and now lifted up to laravel 8.

It's all working.

Now I'm in need to install [laravel-datatables](https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables).

Looking at doc, I discarded v10 because it [requires Laravel 9+](https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/10.0#requirements)
For [same reason](https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/9.0/installation#requirements), I discarded also v9
So I'm trying to [install laravel-datatables v8](https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/8.0/installation)

```
composer require yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle:^8.0
```

I got this

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle 8.0 -> satisfiable by yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle[v8.0.0].
    - yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle v8.0.0 requires illuminate/database 5.4.*|5.5.* -> found illuminate/database[v5.4.0, ..., 5.5.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

I am not able to understand which package/require is conflicting with this package.

This my package.json

```
"require": {
    "php": "^7.3|^8.0",
    "ext-json": "*",
    "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^0.8.1",
    "buzz/laravel-google-captcha": "^2.1",
    "carlos-meneses/laravel-mpdf": "^2.1",
    "davidepastore/codice-fiscale": "^0.7.1",
    "doctrine/dbal": "^3.0",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.4",
    "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.3",
    "laravel/framework": "^8.12",
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.5",
    "laravel/ui": "^3.2",
    "league/flysystem-sftp": "~1.0",
    "maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1",
    "nowakowskir/php-jwt": "^2.0",
    "oriceon/toastr-5-laravel": "^1.0.0",
    "pragmarx/google2fa-laravel": "^1.4",
    "pragmarx/recovery": "^0.2.0",
    "ramsey/uuid": "^4.1",
    "sentry/sdk": "^3.1",
    "sentry/sentry-laravel": "^2.4",
    "shalvah/laravel-jsend": "^2.3",
    "snowfire/beautymail": "^1.1"
},
"require-dev": {
    "facade/ignition": "^2.5",
    "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
    "laravel/sail": "^1.0.1",
    "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.2",
    "nunomaduro/collision": "^5.0",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.3.3"
},
```

Same problem with v7

> Please note: we cannot, for internal policy, use -dev branches

Trying to install v9  ...

```
  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle 9 -> satisfiable by yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle[v9.0.0].
    - yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle v9.0.0 requires illuminate/database 5.8.* -> found illuminate/database[v5.8.0, ..., 5.8.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
```

Comment: `composer require yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle:7.0-dev`

Comment: @AbdullaNilam: why this should solve? anyway it doesn't solves the problem and also we cannot use -dev branches in our projects due to internal stability requirements.

Comment: @AbdullaNilam as you can see on Packagist, v7 of that package is only compatible with Laravel v5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written in the error message: `yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle` in v8 is only compatible with Laravel v5, and you are using Laravel v8.

Try to use `composer require yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle:^9.0` - this version is compatible with Laravel v5 to v8. Next time you are facing such a problem, have a look at the constraints of different versions of the package. Packagist has a pretty nice overview of the compatible versions, for example at https://packagist.org/packages/yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle#v9.21.2 where you can see the dependencies for the latest v9 version of that datatables package

Comment: your answer suggested me to try every single version and I finally found that using `^9.*` successfully installs the v9.21. So thank you !

Comment: "It's not true" - what does that mean?

Comment: sorry, my fault

Answer (score 1):

I accepted answer from Nico Haase because it helped me found the solution, but this is the exact solution for my exact case

```
composer require yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle:^9.*
```

It installed the 9.21.x version and it's compatibile with my actual set of package

Comment: Is there any good reason to use **two** selection modifiers? Anything not working with `^9.0` that is working better with `^9.*`?

Comment: I have no explanation, but ^9.0 is not trying to install same as ^9.*

Comment: Which version would it install instead?

Comment: With 9.0 it do not install anything because it says there is not suitable version available due to other conflicts. with 9.* instead it works. I've no explanations